# Resetting A webform on the ClientSide

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a webform with 3 textboxes, a checkbox and a Reset button. I need these to be reset to null values when i click the button "Reset" and i need it to be a Client-Side operation. The JS code that i have tried for this is as follows but for some reason it doesnt work. Any Help PLease?

```
<code>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resetForm() {
            document.getElemenyById("<%=txtbox1.ClientID%>").value = "";
            return false;
        }

    </script>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="wbtnReset" runat="server" Text="RESET PAGE"     CssClass="stdHyperlink" Font-Bold="True" OnClientClick="javascript:return resetForm()"/>


</code>
```

Comment: use <input type="reset" value="Reset Page"> instead of a link

Comment: i kind of have a design requirement to use that particular linkbutton only.
isnt there a workaround for that control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetForm() {
       document.getElemenyById("<%=txtbox1.ClientID%>").value = "";
}
</script>
<asp:LinkButton ID="wbtnReset" runat="server" Text="RESET PAGE"     CssClass="stdHyperlink" Font-Bold="True" OnClientClick="resetForm()" CausesValidataion = "false"/>
```

you can do it the simple way if you are using .NET 4.0. use **ClientIDMode="Static"** and use below line in javascript

```
document.getElemenyById("txtbox1").value = "";
```

hope it helps

Comment: that is strange. try running these statements var txtbox =  document.getElemenyById("<%=txtbox1.ClientID%>"); alert(txtbox.value); txtbox.value = "";             alert is just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the form using javascript, you need to call reset method on the form object.

The below should help you do what you need.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="wbtnReset" runat="server" Text="RESET PAGE" CssClass="stdHyperlink" Font-
Bold="True" OnClientClick="javascript:this.form.reset(); return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JS for this. Just try `<input type="reset" value="Reset Form">` or `<button type="reset">Reset Form</button>`. This does not delete all data but restores the inital state of the form.